# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key .'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I got this error on 1 of my views. That view worked before and suddenly stopped. I searched for this error and found similar ones but instead of this `.'` others usually get the name of a parameter or outlet that causes the problem. I have no parameters, methods or outlets named like this. I tried searching in Hierarchy but no results were found. No idea what to do. If need some code please tell me which parts as Im completely clueless and i will add.

Comment: Can you please put code here?

Comment: Have you checked you nib files/story board? It might come from there

Comment: any specific part as im unsure which causes it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message comes from an exception raised by `setValue:forKey:` when using an empty string (`@""`) as a key.

On views, KVC is used during nib loading to connect IBOutlets. So look through your nib or storyboard for a connection to an empty outlet.

Comment: yeh somehow i had 3 same things attached to one outlet, deleting two fixed the problem. thank you :)